# IntellliJ Idea (scala) change color settings for syntax error

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, appearance

Does anyone know what setting controls the appearance of a line containing a compilation error in IntelliJ Idea?

I use the standard "Darcula" theme (which I like a lot), and compilation errors are shown just barely changing the text background color of the offending line. I have a hard time seeing them because I partially color-blind, so would like to change that to something brighter. Otherwise, when I click on an error in the compilation tool, I cannot tell right away in which, of the many buffers I have open, the error resides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings->Editor->Colors and Fonts->General then scroll down to Error in the list.

Comment: Not the same thing. That settings controls what the batch inspection produces. I refer to what happens when you run the compilation, and an error is found which the inspection did not detect. In this case, double-clicking on the error message line in the compilation tool window places the cursor at the offending line. But if I have many source buffers open, it is not obvious in which one of them that line is, since the highlight is so subtle.

Comment: For me it is the same thing. Any errors in the message window output after compilation result in highlighted controlled by `Error`.